# Proving complex analytic: Unsolvable Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

> I need to show that $f(z)$ is nowhere analytic, where $$ f(z) = e^{z\operatorname{Re}(z)}.$$

Letting $z = x + yi$,

$$ f(x,y)=e^{x^2}e^{xyi}=e^{x^2}(\cos(xy)+i\sin(xy))$$

and letting $$u(x,y)=e^{x^2}\cos(xy),\quad v(x,y)=e^{x^2}\sin(xy),$$

we have:

\begin{align}u_x &= e^{x^2}(2x\cos(xy)-y\sin(xy))\\ u_y &= -e^{x^2}x\sin(xy) \\
v_x &= e^{x^2}(2x\sin(xy)+y\cos(xy))\\v_y &= e^{x^2}x\cos(xy)\end{align}

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$, I end up with the equations:

$$ x\cos(xy) = y\sin(xy) $$
$$ -x\sin(xy) = y\cos(xy) $$

1. Is this it? Am I able to conclude using these two equations?
2. If not, am I supposed to show that $f(z)$ is nowhere analytic by some other method?

Comment: Thanks for the edit helps! My first question haha

Answer (score 1):

Note that from the two equations, we get $$\frac{x\cos xy}{-x\sin xy}=\frac{y\sin xy}{y\cos xy}\implies -\cot xy=\tan xy\implies \tan^2 xy=-1$$ which is absurd for $x,y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.